# Error MSB4019 when using the MSBuild API while MSBuild.exe works fine

Tags: c#, c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing a C# application that will use the MSBuild API to build a C++ project. The C++ project I am testing with is a completely empty project. When I try to compile it with MSBuild.exe via the command line it works fine. I use

```
MSBuild.exe C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj /p:Platform=x86
```

But when I instead use the MSBuild API as such:

```
Dictionary<string, string> globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Configuration", "Debug" }, { "Platform", "x86" } };
BuildParameters buildParameters = new BuildParameters(new ProjectCollection()) { Loggers = new List<ILogger> { new ConsoleLogger(LoggerVerbosity.Detailed) } };
BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(@"C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj", globalProperty, "4.0", new[] { "Build" }, null);
BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParameters, buildRequest);
```

I get the following error:

```
Building with tools version "15.0".
C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj(27,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Furthermore, when I try this with the MSBuild in Windows\Framework64\v4.0* I **do** get the same error as opposed to when I use the MSBuild located in Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64

To make sure I'm using 15.0 I have added he following to my app.config but it does not seem to make any difference:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

What might I be doing wrong/misunderstanding here?

Update: I found I had references to Microsoft.Build.x of version 4.x. Deleted the references and replaced them with v15.x. The build now **fails with 0 errors and 0 warnings**. See output:

```
Build started 09/11/2017 16:36:04.
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Trying to import C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props using extensions path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild
Property reassignment: $(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)="C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\obj\" (previous value: "obj\") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.props (58,5)
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Trying to import C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Imports\Microsoft.Common.props\ImportBefore\* using extensions path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Property reassignment: $(Platform)="Win32" (previous value: "x86") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props (30,5)
Property reassignment: $(PlatformToolset)="v100" (previous value: "") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\Win32\Platform.default.props (26,5)
Property reassignment: $(PlatformToolset)="v141" (previous value: "v100") at C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj (31,5)
Property reassignment: $(_PlatformFolder)="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\Win32\" (previous value: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\\Platforms\Win32\") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\Win32\Platform.props (15,5)
Property reassignment: $(WindowsSdkDir_10)="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\" (previous value: "") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.props (18,5)
Property reassignment: $(TargetExt)=".exe" (previous value: "") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props (29,5)
Property reassignment: $(WindowsSdkDir_81)="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\" (previous value: "") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props (55,5)
Property reassignment: $(NETFXKitsDir)="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\" (previous value: "") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props (163,5)
Property reassignment: $(NETFXSDKDir)="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\" (previous value: "") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props (165,5)
Property reassignment: $(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86)="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools" (previous value: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86;") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props (169,5)
Property reassignment: $(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64)="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64" (previous value: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64;") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props (170,5)
Property reassignment: $(_PropertySheetDisplayName)="Multi-byte Character Support" (previous value: "Core Windows Libraries") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.MultiByteCharSupport.props (15,5)
Property reassignment: $(_PropertySheetDisplayName)="Application" (previous value: "Multi-byte Character Support") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Application.props (15,5)
Property reassignment: $(ExtensionsToDeleteOnClean)="*.cdf;*.cache;*.obj;*.obj.enc;*.ilk;*.ipdb;*.iobj;*.resources;*.tlb;*.tli;*.tlh;*.tmp;*.rsp;*.pgc;*.pgd;*.meta;*.tlog;*.manifest;*.res;*.pch;*.exp;*.idb;*.rep;*.xdc;*.pdb;*_manifest.rc;*.bsc;*.sbr;*.xml;*.metagen;*.bi;C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe.manifest;C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Debug\Project1.tlb;C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Debug\Project1.pdb;C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe;C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Debug\Project1.bsc;C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Debug\Project1.ilk;C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe.intermediate.manifest" (previous value: "*.cdf;*.cache;*.obj;*.obj.enc;*.ilk;*.ipdb;*.iobj;*.resources;*.tlb;*.tli;*.tlh;*.tmp;*.rsp;*.pgc;*.pgd;*.meta;*.tlog;*.manifest;*.res;*.pch;*.exp;*.idb;*.rep;*.xdc;*.pdb;*_manifest.rc;*.bsc;*.sbr;*.xml;*.metagen;*.bi") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets (35,5)
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Trying to import C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\* using extensions path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Property reassignment: $(MSBuildAllProjects)=";C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.targets;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.NETFramework.CurrentVersion.props" (previous value: ";C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.targets") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.NETFramework.CurrentVersion.props (29,5)
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
__________________________________________________
Project "C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj" 
(Build target(s)):

Building with tools version "15.0".

Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
The thread 0x219c has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Build FAILED.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

Comment: I got the same result as you with `BuildManager`, after search the internet， I found there is a bug on the Microsoft.Build v15.x:https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2369, This may casue this issue.

Comment: It seems you're right. I had the one assemblyBinding in my config already, it seems all that was needed is to do the same for the other references. I'll add an aswer shortly and refer to your comment. Thanks for the link, hadn't come across that one yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Leo-MSFT pointed out in a comment to my question, there is a bug in Microsoft.Build version 15.x (see https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2369). The solution - or rather, temporary work-around - is to add the following to the config file as linked in the post (from: https://github.com/IntelliTect/Coalesce/commit/4d9024ba441af39c8e77e5d30174e67317ed91e0):

```
<runtime>
<!-- TODO: We can probably remove this once MSBuild issue 2369 is fixed: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2369#issuecomment-323139518-->
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

This fix works for Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3.